# RSpec takes forever

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have just started doing TDD (and basically testing in general so bear with me). I am following [The Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) and I now have the following in the spec folder:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end
  end

end
```

The whole process from when I tap the play button saying that I want to run the tests until it is done take 38.75 seconds!! The two tests take 6.0053 seconds. What is going on in Ruby-land?

I don't know yet if this is integration testing or unit testing but I read a post about making one directory with integration tests and another with unit tests. I am using RubyMine on a PC with Windows 7 and SSD. How can I do TDD if I have to wait 40 seconds each time I run the test?

Comment: Which Ruby version are you using? Ruby 1.9.3 got a major boost when it comes to start up time. That might help a bit.

Comment: And why would anyone close this as "doesn't" fit Q&A. Care to explain.

Comment: Is running the tests from outside RubyMine (i.e. in the terminal) any faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because every time you autotest or rspec test your Rails tests, it needs to load the entire Rails environment. One way to avoid re-loading the entire Rails environment for each test is to use Spork

[Spork Docs](http://spork.rubyforge.org/)

[Spork Railscasts by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork)

and a lot is covered about Rspec and how to set it up at:

[Ruby On Rails Tutorial book by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec%3aTDD)

Comment: When you use Windows you can't use Spork.

Comment: It also shouldn't take that long to load the environment in the first place.

Comment: How about Guard (guard-spork)? I don't have a windows PC. But the wait is pretty inconvenient...